Capitalized words in sentiment analysis
I'm currently working with data of customers reviews on products from Sephora. my task to classify them to sentiments : negative, neutral , positive .
A common technique of text preprocessing is to lower case all the words , but in this situation upper case words like 'AMAZING' can hide significant emotion behind them and turning all the word to lower case can cause information loss. would be happy for your opinion in the subject should i still lower case all the words? i personally think about creating more classes and  distinction between sentiments as good , very good than just positive to include the importance of this upper case words .
this is my current code :
from itertools import chain

def is_upper_case(text):
  return [word for word in text.split() if word.isupper() and word != 'I']

unique_upper_words = set(chain.from_iterable(all_reviews['review_text'].apply(is_upper_case)))
print(unique_upper_words)


If you are using a BERT-based model (or any other LLM) to do the actual classification I would recommend to not use any preprocessing at all (at least when it comes to capitalization), as these models were pre-trained on non-preprocessed data.
If you want to then do any kind of analysis on the resulting labeled sentences you could lowercase everything to group n-grams and to simplify the analysis.
If you are thinking about having multiple classes to have a better distinction between the prediction, I think it would make most sense if you switch to a sentiment regression instead of a classification, where you predict a value in a continuous range. This comes somewhat natural to the fine-tuning of language models as in a normal classification you would take a continuous output from the model and map it to categorical classes using something like softmax, so for your needs you can just skip that last step and directly use the model output. Many python ML frameworks for fine-tuning or using language models have their own classes for regression tasks, check out this repository as an example.

thanks :) if Im using BERT should i still clean the data in terms of deleting url links and stuff like that?

I think the opinions on that are split, in my opinion there is mostly no point to it, except when there is something very frequent in your data that BERT has rarely seen in its training data. For example, let's say you use a lot of raw Reddit comment texts that look something like this: this is ***bold-italic formatted text***, this is >!a spoiler!< and this is [a link](https://reddit.com). Then if you use the original BERT variant it hasn't really seen much text formatted like this as it was trained on the BookCorpus + Wikipedia, so removing these formattings might improve performance.

I would recommend to try both approaches and see what gives the better results (in terms of sentiment classification accuracy/regression score metrics)
